# Save a fetched entity in different context

Tags: entity-framework

I fetched an entity using a context. Then I made some changes to the entity and now I'd like to save the entity using a different context. I use the `AttachTo` method but I'm getting this error.

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must Detach before you can AttachTo.

That said, your life will be *much* simpler if you use only one context.